# Plotting a column of a csv file using matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('PracTest5/addresses_h.txt')


subset = new_df.loc[:7, "Postcode"]
plt.plot(subset)
plt.xlabel("Row Number")
plt.ylabel("Postcode")
plt.title("Postcode Data")
plt.show()
```

In this code the graph I get is the on where they have marked the y-axis values in the same order as in the data column what i want to do the values in the y-axis should be marked in ascending order

Comment: the file being read is `txt` and not `csv`.

Comment: also, did you try this? `plt.gca().invert_yaxis()` ?